# Split an object into multiple parts within specific vert/face amount

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

Currently porting a map to a game. The game has a limit of 254 vertices, or 254 faces (whichever comes first), per collision surface mesh. Broken topology doesn't matter as this mesh is used only for collision surfaces (road/dirt/grass etc.) Mesh is around 60,000 verts / 95,000 faces. What would be the best way to separate the entire mesh in bulk into parts under 254 verts/faces ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the best way the easiest way?  Where number of objects doesn't matter?  Rip all edges (edge split modifier limited by angle 0, apply), separate by loose parts ('p' separate in edit mode.)  Your 60k face object turns into 60k one-face objects.  I'm assuming you have no faces containing greater than 254 vertices, which seems reasonable.